# Google Compute Engine Auto Scaling

Tags: google-compute-engine

My site is a bit more of a static site. The site is based on word-press now, and I am thinking of using auto scale feature.

The problem is that I am not good at startup scripts like python, java, etc...

I am more comfortable with bash script.

Is there a way create a snapshot of a production compute-engine and use it as a template instead of instance group without startup script complexity?

I have two instances, one is an individual instance and one is an inside instance group for auto scale.  Whenever there is a update in my site, I have to change it in individual instance and move the snapshot disk as template in instance group and everything will be updated.

My question is, is that workable or do I really have to work on startup script?

Any friendly advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: or in easy words how can i auto scale my wordpress site. because the documentation is going a bit over my head.

Comment: What does "a bit more of a static site" mean? Is there any stateful services (like MySQL databases) running on your VM? Are databases in read-write mode or read-only mode? To be able to use Autoscaler feature of GCE managed instance group, the VMs need to be stateless.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, static means that the site contents are not getting changed very often. database is read and write. i am aware of the backend process i am confuse at the point that when i have to update my site how would i do it. because the  machine was based on a img that i have to create from a VM. so the confusion is, in case of small change do i always have to create a new image then use it in the VM instance group so that all new Autoscale VM can be of update data.

Answer (score 0):

Some bash skills should be enough to write a startup script and not use the additional instance and image creation at all. See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) for an easy example of that - just put in all bash commands that you use to prepare that instance yourself. This should be relatively easy and allows for easy modification of that process later on.

If you really want to avoid writing the script, what you’ve described should be possible: take an instance that has everything installed as you like it, then delete it keeping the disk and create an image out of that disk.
One minor improvement: you can use an instance from the existing instance group by [abandoning](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/#abandoning_instances) it.